# Symfony2/Twig - Need to use |nl2br for spaces and |raw blog body in twig, can this be done?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using nl2br filter on the blog body to put in spaces. Is it possible to also use another filter on top of this? I would like to use |raw for some html code in the blog body.

e.g., how can I add in the |raw filter on top of this?

```
{% for blogs in blog %}
   <p>{{ blog.blog|nl2br }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use your filters in chain, so:

```
{{ blog.blog|raw|nl2br }}
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed <b></b> do not work with |raw? Is there another way to get bold tags working?

Comment: try `{% autoescape false %}{{ my_variable}}{% endautoescape %}`

Comment: like so? `{% autoescape false %} {{  blog.blog|raw|nl2br }} {% endautoescape %}` That didn't work.

Comment: you don't need `raw` when autoescape is disabled, so `{% autoescape false %}{{ blog.blog|nl2br }}{% endautoescape %}`

Comment: No that didn't work, the html tags are not rendering now, getting `<b>text</b>`

Comment: try `{{ blog.blog|striptags('<b>')|raw|nl2br }}`

Comment: No, still not coming up bold. hmmm

Comment: I think it's something to do with the font I am using and the css that's preventing bold from displaying.